# What’s the Office Mac keyboard shortcut to open the Smart Tag menu?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, office-for-mac

What’s the Office Mac keyboard shortcut to open the Smart Tag menu?

On Windows it’s <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>. The Windows keyboard customization dialog says the shortcut is bound to “Select on Object Control”, which, frustratingly, doesn’t show up in the list of all commands.